# RegEx not working for all inputs in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I am using the following regex in C++

```
std::regex base_regex("[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?");
```

It rejects teh follwoing input

```
email@subdomain.domain.com
```

The same works in java and js. Can someone expalin

Comment: In my test that merely matches this test, the regex_match function returns truth.

Comment: What compiler/version ?

Comment: visual studio 2010

Comment: I could see that it accepts a@c.c.c.ccb.c but not a@c.c.cc.ccb.c or a@c.cc.c.ccb.c or a@cc.c.c.ccb.c   So that means its not accepting more than one character in the domain part before the second last '.'  But I could not find out the mistake in the regex

Comment: Work as expected [Demo](https://ideone.com/queKfQ). Probably a bug in old vs2010.

Comment: @vijin Use a later version of Visual Studio.  You are 2 major versions short of the current version.  The code [works here](http://rextester.com/AREIS75256) using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your regex with vs2010 and vs2015. In vs2010 the match fails, in 2015 not. So I think is a bug of vs2010 implementation.
If you try a little different regex :

```
std::regex base_regex("[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]+");
```

it works.
I simplified the expression. Instead of :

```
[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?
```

I used

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

It's not equal, because it accept '-' at beginning or end of domain/subdomain name, but maybe it could fine for you.